# Centralized webpack config for multiple projects - best practice?

Tags: github, data-structures, npm, webpack, node-modules

> **TL:DR;**
>   How would you centralize a webpack 3.x build setup for multiple modules?

I'm in the planning phase of restructuring my company's entire module library and making them available on npm. This however have created some debate on how to maintain the modules afterwards.

We are running with webpack 3.x and have created a beta version of our build setup, but how would you create a centralized way of having our build setup available for multiple standalone modules?

I would like to have one place where I can update the build setup and be able to use said build setup in all of our modules without having to copy/paste every single improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a module that contains all your build config and setup and the other projects just have a dependency to it.
Take a look at [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) for an inspiration on how to do it.

Also [this section](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#updating-to-new-releases) might help you understand how it can work

Comment: Just to clearify. This module should not go on npm correct? It would be best served as a github dependency?

Comment: That is up to you. If you want to keep it private, you can deploy it to your own repo (e.g. https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) or use a multi workspace setup (e.g. https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2017/08/02/introducing-workspaces/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [airpack](https://github.com/arzyu/airpack) for centralizing webpack config.

It's a solution for modular webpack configuration. Give webpack the ability to read configs automatically from dependencies, and merge them in a more appropriate way.